# XmlStreamReader behaves randomly at the start

Tags: java, xmlstreamreader

I would expect the XmlStreamReader to start at the start of the document (obviously) and then jump to the root of the XML document when I call next() on it. However, scaringly, I see it jump to the first tag with text inside and always omitting the root and often(???) the second tag.

the document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objektliste xmlns="http://www.pixelboxx.de/ns/erco/translations/1.0">
  <uebersetzungen key="122671" attribute="7505">
    <thumbnail>abrakadabra.jpg</thumbnail>
    <text sprache="1031">We like the abla abla abla</text>
    <text sprache="2057">We like the spoonBlaBlaBla[en]</text>
    <text sprache="1036">Wicher</text>
  </uebersetzungen>
  <uebersetzungen key="122679" attribute="7505">
    <thumbnail>122679.jpg</thumbnail>
    <text sprache="1031">Kiefer</text>
    <text sprache="1036">franek</text>
  </uebersetzungen>
</objektliste>
```

Am I going insane, is my eclipse going insane or I don't see something obvious?
The program seems to always omit "objektliste" and usually jump to "thumbnail" first, even though in previous debug sessions it seemed to behave even more random.
help!!!

btw, the code is extremely simple:

```
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader( is);

    while( streamReader.hasNext())
    {
//event type 7 here, everything seems to be ok. 
        streamReader.next();
//bang! armaggeddon - skips the root, jumps to thumbnail.
```

Comment: apparently streamReader.getLocalName() causes at mine the streamreader moving to the next element! is it a known bug???

Answer (score 1):

The call to `streamReader.next()` is event based .

> The next() method causes the reader to read the next parse event. The next() method returns an integer which identifies the type of event just read.
>
> The event type can be determined using getEventType().

I think you may be experiencing issues with the end element events showing up and you were not expecting it.

Using the following code, I see the proper order being processed as expected:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);

while( streamReader.hasNext()) {
  int eventType = streamReader.next();
  switch (eventType) {
      case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
          String elementName = streamReader.getLocalName();
          System.out.println("Element: " + elementName);
          break;
      case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT:
          break;
  }
}
```

Which generates the expected output:

```
Element: objektliste
Element: uebersetzungen
Element: thumbnail
Element: text
Element: text
Element: text
Element: uebersetzungen
Element: thumbnail
Element: text
Element: text
```